# eigen analysis of variables in R

Tags: r, eigenvalue

Is there a way to evaluate Eigen information without using numbers/values in R?

Here is my example, I am working with a three equation system from Bairagi et al 2007, Role of infection on the stability of a predator–prey system with several
response functions—A comparative study. I would like to know if there is a way to analyze a jacobian without using numbers/values (using variables, instead). Following is my example:

Equations

```
dsdtau = expression(b*s-b*s^2-b*s*i-s*i-m*s*p)
didtau = expression(s*i - d*i*p - e*i)
dpdtau = expression(-theta*d*i*p - g*p + theta*m*s*p)
```

Partial derivatives

```
dsds <- D(dsdtau,"s")
dids <- D(dsdtau,"i")
dpds <- D(dsdtau,"p")
dsdi <- D(didtau,"s")
didi <- D(didtau,"i")
dpdi <- D(didtau,"p")
dsdp <- D(dpdtau,"s")
didp <- D(dpdtau,"i")
dpdp <- D(dpdtau,"p")
```

Jacobian

```
j1 <- matrix(c(
dsds,dids,dpds,
dsdi,didi,dpdi,
dsdp,didp,dpdp),
nrow = 3, byrow = TRUE)
```

First, is there a way to coerce R into giving me the full details in matrix form? For example, when I run

```
j1
```

I get

```
     [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      
[1,] Expression Expression Expression
[2,] ?          Expression Expression
[3,] Expression Expression Expression
```

but when I run j1[1], I get:

```
b - b * (2 * s) - b * i - i - m * p
```

which is what I want.

Second, is there a way to analyze this jacobian using the variables rather than plugging in values? For example, at `(s,i,p) = (0,0,0)` there is a trivial equilibrium with `lambda = (b,-e,-g)` which is an unstable saddle point (as all variables are greater than 0) and not particularly exciting. But for non-trivial equilibria the math is more labor intensive, and if R knows a way, I'd love help figuring it out!

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to storing `j1` as a [list](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.html), here's a way to explicitly show each expression. As far as evaluating goes, that's something I would need more time to investigate. For now, the following list of functions seems promising: [`match.call()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.call.html), [`do.call()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/do.call.html), [`eval()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eval.html), and [`get()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/get.html).

```
# store j1
# as a list object
# naming each set of equations
j1 <- 
    list(
          didtau = c( dsds,dids,dpds )
        , dpdtau = c( dsdi,didi,dpdi )
        , dsdtau = c( dsdp,didp,dpdp )
    )

# view the list
j1
# $didtau
# $didtau[[1]]
# b - b * (2 * s) - b * i - i - m * p
# 
# $didtau[[2]]
# -(b * s + s)
# 
# $didtau[[3]]
# -(m * s)
# 
# 
# $dpdtau
# $dpdtau[[1]]
# i
# 
# $dpdtau[[2]]
# s - d * p - e
# 
# $dpdtau[[3]]
# -(d * i)
# 
# 
# $dsdtau
# $dsdtau[[1]]
# theta * m * p
# 
# $dsdtau[[2]]
# -theta * d * p
# 
# $dsdtau[[3]]
# -theta * d * i - g + theta * m * s

# end of script #
```

Comment: I am looking for something I can view as a matrix, but the list option isn't a bad way to go, I could use three lists, one for each row, and that would help with visualizing the results. Thank you.

Comment: @Flick No problem, glad to help. I revised my answer to name each list within `j1` by the equation it represents. For your second question, you may want to explore the [`jacobian()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/numDeriv/versions/2016.8-1/topics/jacobian) function in the [`numDeriv`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/numDeriv/versions/2016.8-1) package for further help.

Comment: Everything in package numDeriv wants numeric values. The example in the book I'm following, Primer of Ecology with R, uses function eval (as suggested above), but that again only works for numerical values. I wouldn't have thought this would be a novel problem so I'm surprised it's not easier to find a solution!